# Is it common to write Diagnostics class in app

Tags: c#, java, debugging, logging

Is this common to write `Diagnostics` class in app? - which do more than just dumping stack trace? If yes what is desired things to be done in it?

I am thinking to write `Diagnostics` class with

- various overloaded `diagnose(Class thisInstance, Exception ex)` one for each more exception-prone class in my app.
- `analyzeEnvironmentVariables()`
- `analyzeAppSettings()`
- `analyzeServers()`
- `diagnodeAll()` : will create instances of all classes and see if they are properly initialized

I will call `diagnose()` in `catch()`:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Diagnostics.diagnose(this,ex);
}
```

In each of `diagnose()`,  I am thinking to

- Dump stack trace
- Dump and analyze members of thisInstance
- call `analyzeEnvironmentVariables();`
- call `analyzeAppSettings();`
- call `analyzeServers();`
- call `diagnoseAll();`
- see if things can be fixed
- attempt restarting app thrice, if it fails all times it stops
- Will echo the diagnosis result finally

Is this done normally? I know if the class cannot actually diagnose things based on analysis of various params the whole class may reduce to somewhat extended logging functionality. But still want to give a second thought to it and want to know whats done usually.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bad idea - generally behaviour at time of exception is similar most times at least when its fatal, so refactoring so there is but one implementation of that is a good move.

Consider not being too dependent on other classes while doing so however - you dont want to tie your entire system up in dependency knots. Also consider what happens if the Diagnostics class throws an exception itself. You don't want to suppress and blow up in unexpected ways.